# Yii deleteAll() records with condition

Tags: php, yii

I've set up a log in process where a verification code is generated, and when successful, is then removed. However, i want to make sure that if there's multiple verification codes for the same user, upon log in success, delete all records for that user.

Here's my code

```
if ($model->validate() && $model->login()) {

    //delete this verification code
    $verificationCode->delete();
    //delete all existing codes for user_id
    VerificationCode::model()->deleteAll('user_id',$user->id);

    Yii::app()->user->setReturnUrl(array('/system/admin/'));

    $this->redirect(Yii::app()->user->returnUrl);
}
```

However, this seems to just delete all the records, regardless on different user_id's in table. Can anyone see where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems you call the function delete() in wrong way ... try passing value this way

```
VerificationCode::model()->deleteAll('user_id = :user_id', array(':user_id' => $user->id));
```

Comment: Thanks, this code is giving me a syntax error and i can't see what is should be?

Comment: Still getting a syntax error, can this condition=>Paramus method be called from a controller?

Comment: Thanks for your help scaisEdge - answer was correct, but syntax was wrong, had to read up on the documentation, deleteAll() params must be passed as an array, like so 

VerificationCode::model()->deleteAll('user_id = :user_id', array(':user_id' => $user->id));

Comment: This isn't correct. It either needs to be deleteAll($condition, $params) or deleteAll($Criteria)

Comment: @HarryB  the right suggestion   was already in comment anyway answer  updated.. thanks ..

Answer (score 6):

If you want to delete record with specified attributes, the cleanest way for this is to use [`deleteAllByAttributes()`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord#deleteAllByAttributes-detail):

```
VerificationCode::model()->deleteAllByAttributes(['user_id' => $user->id]);
```

Answer (score 2):

For Yii2, the [documented](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-activerecord#deleteAll()-detail) way is to use the function `deleteAll()`.

I normally pass the arguments as an array, like so:

```
VerificationCode::deleteAll(['user_id' => $user->id]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, you can use the `afterDelete` method, to make sure that everytime or everywhere someone deletes one verificationCode, your application will also delete every userVerificationCode. Put this in your verificationCode model class:

```
protected function afterDelete()
{
    parent::afterDelete();
    VerificationCode::model()->deleteAll('user_id = :user:id',[':user_id' =>$this->user_id]);
    //... any other logic here
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use below method for deleting all user_id entry from database:

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria;
// secure way for add a new condition
$criteria->condition = "user_id = :user_id ";
$criteria->params[":user_id"] = $user->id;
// remove user related all entry from database
$model = VerificationCode::model()->deleteAll($criteria);
```

or you can use another method directly in controller action

> VerificationCode::model()->deleteAll("user_id= :user_id", [":user_id"
>   =>$user->id]);

use below method for redirecting a URL

> $this->c()->redirect(Yii::app()->createUrl('/system/admin/'));